# How to retrieve data, based upon two date picker controls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select data between two date ranges, (Going to come from a datepicker). I have constructed my query various ways, but still no records show up. I Think its to do with my Where statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select CampaignName AS 'CAMPAIGN NAME', 
campaignDescription AS 'CAMPAIGN DESCRIPTION', 
CASE WHEN EndDate >= GETDATE() and StartDate <= GETDATE() THEN 'ACTIVE' 
WHEN StartDate >= GETDATE() THEN 'PENDING
'ELSE 'CLOSED' END as 'CURRENT STATUS', 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), StartDate,106) + ' - ' +        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),EndDate,106) 
AS 'CAMPAIGN DATES', 
Discount AS 'DISCOUNT', 
[Target] AS 'TARGET', 
Uptake AS 'UPTAKE', 
AddedBy AS 'ADDED BY', 
DateAdded AS 'DATE ADDED' 
FROM Tbl_Campaign 
WHERE EndDate BETWEEN 2015-09-20 AND 2015-10-30
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass dates inside quotes `' '` in following:

```
WHERE EndDate BETWEEN '2015-09-20' AND '2015-10-30'
```

For now you have `INT` `2015-09-20` which is equals to `1986`

Comment: Oh bless you kind sir.